# Redirect to /commerce/payments/complete-payment returns 404

Tags: routes, craft4, plugin-craftcommerce4

I've created a gateway with payment to an external payment provider (offsite).

When the payment is successful I need a redirect to complete the order and payment to: /commerce/payments/complete-payment

I tried: http://www.mysite.test/commerce/payments/complete-payment (returns 404).

**Update:**

I then tried: [http://www.mysite.test/?action=/commerce/payments/complete-payment&commerceTransactionHash=[hash]](http://www.mysite.test/?action=/commerce/payments/complete-payment&commerceTransactionHash=%5Bhash%5D). That seems to be working.

I have a gateway and a requestresponse class to handle what is needed.

What can I do to fix this issue?

From the documentation:
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/extend/payment-gateway-types.html#off-site-payment
and
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/4.x/dev/controller-actions.html#get-payments-complete-payment